# Get random docs based on tags mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 mongodb collections: tracks and tags
now i want to get a random track based on some conditions:

1. If no tag provided: get random track from all documents with no filter
2. If a tag  provided and we can find tracks: get random track with that tag
3. If a tag provided and we cannot find any track with that tag: get a random track with no filter

let me show my code:

my track schema:

```
const trackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: {type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Tag', index: true, default: []},
})
```

my tag schema

```
const tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: Object, required: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true },

})
```

my service methods:

```
    async getRandom(skip: number) {
        const track = await this.trackModel
            .findOne()
            .skip(skip)
        return track
    }

    async getRandomTrack(tag = null) {
        let filter = {}
        if (tag) {
            filter = { tags: { $in: tag } }
        }

        const count = await this.trackModel.count()
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
        
        if (tag) {
            const tracks = await this.trackModel.find(filter).select(['id']).lean()
            if (tracks.length === 0) {
                return await this.getRandom(random)                
            } else {
                const randomId = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length)]
                const track = await this.getTrack(randomId._id.toString())
                return track
            }
        } else {
            return await this.getRandom(random)
        }
    }
```

this piece of code works fine but i assume in larger scale it will run into performance issue. is there a better way to handle?

Comment: Check out `$sample`

Comment: @user20042973 can you please send me a currect pieace of code to achieve my goal?